# Will there be situations where the returned fields from the Places API is null?

Tags: android, google-places-api

So I'm using Places API to allow users to pick street addresses. I create a request to the Places API in this manner:

```
        val fields = listOf(
            Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS
        )
        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
            .setCountries(listOf(viewModel.getCurrentCountry()))
            .setTypesFilter(listOf(PlaceTypes.ADDRESS))
            .build(requireContext())
        placesPickerLauncher.launch(intent)
```

Once the user picks a location, I obtain the `Place` object and parse it in this way:

```
fun onSelectPlace(place: Place) {
        val addressComponents = place.addressComponents
        val suburb =
            addressComponents?.asList()?.find { it.types.contains("locality") }?.name
        val state = addressComponents?.asList()
            ?.find { it.types.contains("administrative_area_level_1") }?.shortName
        val postalCode =
            addressComponents?.asList()?.find { it.types.contains("postal_code") }?.name
        val countryCode =
            addressComponents?.asList()?.find { it.types.contains("country") }?.shortName
...
}
```

As you can see, some fields from the Places object can be null. My worry is that if we were to display these fields in the UI it would show up as `null`. I also worry that some results from the Places API would have null coordinates. Given the way I've set up my request for the Places API, would the returned results have the necessary fields, including the coordinates?